# Server shutdown suddenly

Tags: shutdown, oracle-linux

One of our production server shutdown suddenly for unknown reason. I've checked the logs and found this:

> init: tty (/dev/tty5) main process (2399) killed by TERM signal
>
> Dec 7 12:02:32 rh init: tty (/dev/tty6) main process (2407)
>   killed by TERM signal
>
> Dec 7 12:02:34 rh oddjobd: oddjobd shutdown succeeded
>
> Dec 7 12:02:34 rh abrtd: Got signal 15, exiting
>
> Dec 7 12:02:35 rh xinetd[2104]: Exiting...
>
> Dec 7 12:02:37 rh rtkit-daemon[2601]: Sucessfully made
>   thread 18164 of process 18164 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '500'
>   high priority at nice level -11.
>
> Dec 7 12:02:37 rh rtkit-daemon[2601]: Sucessfully made
>   thread 18167 of process 18167 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '500'
>   high priority at nice level -11.
>
> Dec 7 12:02:37 rh pulseaudio[18167]: pid.c: Daemon already
>   running.
>
> Dec 7 12:02:39 rh acpid: exiting

What in the blue world is this `oddjobd`?

Comment: Plopping *oddjobd* into Google here results in explanations of what it is. E.g., https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/oddjob.git/plain/doc/oddjob.html

Comment: Also, what is your actual question here? You've posted the end of a shutdown log (not the beginning, which might actually say why the server shut down), and the only thing you actually asked is what oddjobd is.